# What rows or columns or matrices do you multiply to find the entry in row $1$, column $1$ of $CDE$

Tags: linear-algebra

**This question was taken from MIT OCW and *Introduction to Linear Algebra* by Gilbert Strang.**

For example, I know that the entry in row $3$, column $4$ of $AB$ would be (row $3$ of $A$)$ \cdot  $(column $4$ of $B$)

I'm having trouble seeing how I can apply this same reasoning to three matrices at once.

A hint would be better than the actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}CDE &= [CD]E = \begin{bmatrix}[\text{1st row of $C$}]D \\ \vdots \\ [\text{last row of $C$}]D\end{bmatrix}E\\ &= C[DE] = C\begin{bmatrix}D[\text{1st col of $E$}] & \cdots & D[\text{last col of $E$}]\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Comment: I wrote out abstracted matrices, $C$, $D$, and $E$ and I think it makes more sense now. I'll try to explain it to you and tell me if I got it right, please. So, the entry in row $1$, column $1$ of the matrix when I multiply $CD$ will be ${ C }_{ 11 }{ D }_{ 11 }+{ C }_{ 21 }{ D }_{ 21 }+...+{ C }_{ m1 }{ D }_{ m1 }$

Then, when I multiply $(CD)E$, the entry in row $1$, column $1$ of this new matrix will be the the dot product of the first row of $CD$ and the first column of $E$

Therefore, a shorter way of stating this would be (row $1$ of $C$)$\cdot$ $D$ $\cdot $(column $1$ of $E$)

Comment: Yep.  That's right.  Just FYI you'll see a formula like (row matrix)(square matrix)(column matrix) again when you get to something called *bilinear forms*.